# WSO2 ESB 4.0.3 - How to specify sslProtocol parameter for transport listner HttpCoreNIOSSLListener

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

We are working on MAC OSX 10.8.4 with Java 6 - 64 bit. We are working on WSO2 4.0.3 ESB. I have successfully enabled SSL for the ESB cluster we have deployed.

Our UAT is going on and Information security of our company has raised issue saying that "SSL Server Supports Weak Encryption Vulnerability". I am using HttpCoreNIOSSLListener transport listner.

They said typically in tomcat you will have to change server.xml to add following parameter to connector

```
sslProtocol="SSLv3" 
ciphers="SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5,SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA,SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA"
```

Since for WSO2 ESB 4.0.3 there is no server.xml for embedded tomcat as far as I understand, how can I make sure that data services deployed ESB uses SSLv3 protocol for SSL communication and among above ciphers?

I would appreciate quick response. Whole WSO2 evaluation for the solution depends upon passing Information security review. Looking at the OS you know which big company I am working for.

thanks in anticipation.
Abhijit

Answer (score 0):

WSO2 ESB 4.0.3 comes with [nhttp transport](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB403/HTTPS-NIO+Transport) by default and you should be able to change the transport in axis2 xml to use [HTTPS Servlet Transport](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB403/HTTPS+Servlet+Transport).

[HTTPS Servlet Transport](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB403/HTTPS+Servlet+Transport) has the required parameters you need as it is based on Apache Tomcat's connector implementation.

I need to check whether same parameters can be used with nhttp. i.e. without changing transports.

AFAIK, it is not recommended to

1. change default transports in ESB (if you need high performance).
2. deploy services within ESB.

You should also be able to use [WSO2 DSS](http://wso2.com/products/data-services-server/), which has servlet connectors by default.

Any particular reason for using WSO2 ESB 4.0.3. It's recommended to use the latest version [WSO2 ESB 4.7.0](http://wso2.com/products/enterprise-service-bus/).

Comment: Hi Isuru  Thnaks a lot for quick resposne. Can you please check if the same parameter can be used without changing the transport. Please let me know. If this goes through WSO2 will be all over in the large group in the company.

Comment: I will check and let you know.

Comment: I'm discussing this at WSO2 dev@ mailing list. Refer http://mail.wso2.org/mailarchive/dev/2013-July/020266.html You can specify the SSL Protocol parameter in ESB 4.7.0. Will you be able to upgrade to ESB 4.7.0?

Comment: Please let me know if this is possible with NIO transport listener. It is not possible to upgrade to 4.7.0 as if this issue is mitigated we will have Information Security clearance for change of the architecture to WSO2. If we upgrade to 4.7.0 we have to do this clearance process again which takes 2-3 months which will affect other groups time lines.

Comment: Hi, So it seems we might have to patch the version you are using. I assume you are only using WSO2 ESB 4.0.3. Have you subscribed to WSO2 mailing lists? http://wso2.com/mail Please subscribe if possible. Then it would be easy to communicate and provide a solution for this.

Comment: Hi Isuru Thanks a lot for the help. Can you please let me know which mailing list I have subscribe? Thanks again for all your help. Abhijit

Comment: Hi! Please subscribe to developer list. mailto:dev-request@wso2.org?subject=subscribe

Comment: Hi Abhijit, Do you need to enable those specific ciphers only? Will it be enough to specify only SSL Protocol? I just went through the code (both Synapse and Tomcat) and we can modify the Synapse to configure SSL protocol by parameter, but I'm afraid I have no idea how to enable those ciphers only with existing code base of Synapse. I can help to modify SSL Protocol of ESB only. I think it will be good if you can contact WSO2 support http://wso2.com/support and get help. Since you are in final stages of the UAT, contacting support is the best option to get an answer quickly.

Comment: Hi Isuru, We need to specify SSL Protocol as well as those ciphers. So we have to use servlet transport. I have another question "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17844440/wso2-esb-4-0-3-can-we-have-wsdleprprefix-for-https-servlet-transport" Can you please help me with this one since it is related to this change?

Comment: Hi Any updates... if we can not get past WSO2 will not be platform for this company. I would be thankful if you can provide the sample servlet transport listner axis2.xml configuration for HTTPS trnasport with above parameters?

Comment: Hi Abhijit, Could you please send a mail to dev@ mailing list.